# Separate web server from home network

Tags: security, vlan

I'm relatively new to advanced home networking and I want to host a web server at home. I've purchased a domain and will be using nodns or something similar to point my domain to my home IP address.

What I want to accomplish is to host a web server on my home network but not allow this server to communicate with any other hardware on the network.

My current home network looks like so:

[image]

I imagine I'll be using port forwarding to send HTTP traffic to the web server but I'm unsure as to how to set up the main wireless router and my switch such that the web server is isolated on it's own VLAN and cannot talk to the rest of the network.

My main issue is that I only have one physical cable going from the main router upstairs to my switch downstairs. On the switch downstairs I have the web server connected as well as other devices. I want to avoid changing the physical layout of the network and running a second cable from upstairs to downstairs isn't an option.

Is it even possible to accomplish what I'm looking to do with my current network layout? I have DDWRT running on both the main router and the switch connected to the web server so I do have some flexibility there.

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to have a web server that is only accessible within your own network or a specific subnet.  It is indeed possible to do that.

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible to have a web server on its own vlan so that it can be accessed from the internet but so the web server itself cannot access anything else on my home network.

I do not want to change the physical layout of my home network but I also do not want anyone to have access to the devices on my network if the web server gets compromised.

Comment: Can a web server be on it's own vlan, and be accessible from the internet, this indeed can be possible.  You would port forward the traffic on port 80/443 to a router/network switch which the only device connected to it were devices, you wanted accessible to the internet.  **This is typically how networks are designed when a web server exists by the way.,**  You keep your intranet away from the internet accessible vlan.

Comment: "I do not want to change the physical layout of my home network" - It won't be possible with your current configuration more then likely due to the other intranet devices that would be on the same vlan.

Comment: I figured it would have to go that way Ramhound. The ultimate solution was to just move the raspberri pi into the baby's room where the router is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It won't be possible with your current configuration more then likely due to the other intranet devices that would be on the same vlan. – Ramhound Nov 8 '17 at 21:55

This ended up being the answer. I was figured it would have to be that way but I was hoping there would be some kind of network trick that could make it possible.

Raspberri Pi was moved into the baby's room where the router lives.